# Running scrapy on django project in views

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am trying to run a scrapy script in one of my views behind the scenes to get some information for me and have tried many different ways like using crawl, crawlprocess, scrapyd etc. and all of them return errors. The scrapy script runs perfectly from its own file but when I try to run it from views I get many errors. Any suggestions are appreciated. (Trying to add it to def at the bottom of the views file).

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    product = input("What product are you looking for? Keywords help for specific products: ")
    name = "Product_spider"
    allowed_domains=['www.amazon.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords='+product]
    #so that websites will not block access to the spider
    download_delay = 30

    def parse(self, response):
        crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()
        # xpath is similar to an address that is used to find certain elements in HTML code,this info is then extracted
        product_title = response.xpath('//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@title').extract()
        product_price = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"s-price")]/text()').extract()
        product_url = response.xpath('//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@href').extract()
        # yield goes through everything once, saves its spot, does not save info but sends it to the pipeline to get processed if need be
        yield{'product_title': product_title, 'product_price': product_price, 'url': product_url,}
                               #it is checking the same url, no generality, need to find, maybe just do like 5 pages, also see if you can have it sort from high to low and find match with certain amount of key words
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })
    process.crawl(ProductSpider)
    process.start()   





from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import CustomUCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Items
from django.core.signals import request_finished
from django.http import HttpRequest
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapyd_api import ScrapydAPI


# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = CustomUCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signuptemplate.html', {'form': form})


def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
            #not_active means maybe banned or something
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'username or password not correct')
                return redirect('login')
    return render(request,'design.html')


def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')


def logout_method(request):
    return logout(request,'design.html')


def newitem(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        current_u = request.user
        temp_Item = Items(Item = request.POST['new-item-input'],Itemuser = current_u)
        temp_Item.save()
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request,'newitem.html')


def currentprices(request):
    #python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload
    items = Items.objects.all()
    scrapyd = ScrapydAPI('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
    scrapyd.schedule('Yourhub2','ProductSpider')
    return render(request,'currentprices.html',{'items':items})
```

Comment: why don't you try using beautifulSoup instead?

Comment: Instead of running a spider, you can try `html_resp = urlopen(request)`, pass the response to `response = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(html_resp)` . Now you can scrape from reponse like `response.xpath(\bla\bla)`. I can give a detailed answer if you'd like. Also I wouldn't suggest switching from scrapy to BS4 like the comment above.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, do you mean i can code this right inside the view instead of using a seperate spider class?

Comment: def currentprices(request):
items = Items.objects.all()
html_resp = urlopen("https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2/144-5538193-4006927?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ssd")
response = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(html_resp)
product_title = response.xpath('//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@title').extract()
product_price = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"s-price")]/text()').extract()
product_url = response.xpath('//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@href').extract()
yield{'product_title': product_title, 'product_price': product_price, 'url': product_url,}

Comment: return render(request,'currentprices.html',{'items':items})

Comment: I tried this and it gives the error: AttributeError Exception Value: 
'generator' object has no attribute 'get'